# Can cold adamantium cut through adamantium?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-origins-wolverine, adamantium, the-wolverine

In *X-Men Origins: Wolverine (2009)*, Wolverine is able to decapitate Deadpool, who if I understand correctly, had a bone structure made of adamantium.

But later in *The Wolverine (2013)*, which, correct me if I'm wrong, but I assume it's part of the same continuity, Wolverine fights Silver Samurai, who pilots a robot made of adamantium. When Silver Samurai attacks him with his adamantium sword, he's able to hold him back, but as soon as Silver Samurai turns one of his sword in a burning sword, Silver Samurai is able to cut through Wolverine's adamantium claws with his adamantium burning sword.

Later, when Wolverine has the chance to attack Silver Samurai again, instead of attacking him with his other intact adamantium claws, he looks for one of the Silver Samurai sword that this last dropped, and in desperation screams "come on!", expecting the sword to start burning, like if that was the only chance he had to harm Silver Samurai. Then, with the burning adamantium sword, he is able to cut the robot head made of adamantium.

Why didn't he use his adamantium claws to cut/harm Silver Samurai?
Can cold adamantium cut through adamantium?

Comment: Wasn't the Silver Samurai's sword tachyonic, rather than super-heated?

Comment: *"but I assume it's part of the same continuity"* << All the x-men movies are part of the same continuity, except where they're not. I mean, when a new x-men movie comes out it often has tons of inconsistencies with prior x-men movies. In particular, this happened several times: character X from the comics was used in movie A but as a minor secondary character. Then in movie B they decide to use character X more fully, so they decide to not care about consistency with movie A regarding character X.

Comment: For instance Sabertooth appears as a secondary, mostly boring, villain in the first X-men, then reappears as a completely different character in X-men Origin: Wolverine. Emma Frost is in X-men Origins: Wolverine as a very minor character, then reappears completely differently in X-men First Class. And of course Deadpool is completely different between X-men origins: Wolverine and his own movie.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Adamantium can't cut Adamantium

However, note that Deadpool's neck also contains cartilage:

[image: diagram of the human neck showing bone and cartilage]

Wolverine only needs to hit one of those soft points to sever the neck.

Whereas the 'Silver Samurai' has no such weak point.

Otherwise we see that the franchise doesn't treat heated Adamantium consistently.

It has to be super heated before infusing Wolverine's bones, then when it sets it's 'indestructable' (as per William Stryker, various movies). However the superheating seen in The Wolverine at least goes against this logic, in that not only is the Adamantium able to be melted after setting, but it's the heated sword does the cutting not the cold Adamantium of Wolverine's claws.

Comment: It doesn't seem likely that Logan only hit the soft points in Wade's neck, since he drove not one but _three_ of his claws through Wade's neck at the same time. Also, his claws were super-heated at the time, and his fight with the Silver Samurai proves that super-heated adamantium can cut through adamantium in this universe. Furthermore, adamantium bullets can also penetrate adamantium in this universe.

Comment: @Logic these are all excellent points

Comment: It's not just heat that works though - Silver Samurai also later taps into Wolverine's powers by drilling into the stubs of his severed claws.  I guess drills produce some heat via friction, but nothing like the glowing red-hot we saw in his sword earlier.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman that makes even less sense...

Answer (score 13):

In *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*, Logan's claws were super-heated by blocking Weapon XI's optic blasts, just before he used them to decapitate Weapon XI, so that doesn't seem inconsistent with what was shown in *The Wolverine*.

It should be possible for Logan's claws to cut through adamantium *without* being super-heated, provided they're propelled with sufficient force. William Stryker was able to pierce Logan's skull with adamantium bullets in *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*.

However, the fight with the Silver Samurai suggests that Logan himself isn't strong enough to generate that much force. The Silver Samurai exoskeleton was likely stronger than he is, and *it* couldn't cut through his claws until it super-heated its swords.

Comment: I had completely forgotten about how the claws get heated in *Origins*.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - I didn't recall that part myself until I reviewed the scene.

Comment: Having also forgotten, and reviewed the scene, I shall now proceed to repress that memory in order to personal dissatisfaction. This comment serves purely as a warning, to future-me, that I don't want to see it again.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that the adamantium bullet pierced through logan's skull? My understanding has always been that it justs hits him very very hard and caused a head trauma, as opposed to a normal bullet which would have deformed upon impact against the adamantium skull, and would have dissipated a lot of kinetic energy because of that deformation.

Comment: @Stef - The evidence is right there in my answer. Play the second video clip and you can see Stryker shooting Wolverine in the forehead and producing a visible hole in his skull. Stryker also remarked on the bullets going _"through his thick skull"_ in an earlier scene.

Comment: I just rewatched the video several times and I see no evidence that the bullet went through Wolverine's skull. In face around https://youtu.be/ZVzMB2vRNz8?t=32 there is a "blink" sound when the bullet hits Wolverine in the head and some special effect as if the bullet was either ricocheting or producing sparks. Then a few seconds later when Wolvie is down on the ground, Stryker shoots a second bullet and there is an even louder "blink" sound as if the bullet is really ricocheting. I also saw no visible hole in his skull. There is a visible metal mark where the bullet hit him, no hole.

Comment: I had watched this movie a long time ago so I thought maybe you had more information and I was misremembering, but now that I have rewatched this scene I'm convinced that no, the bullet indeed did not pierce the skull.

Comment: @Stef - If this video clip isn't enough to convince you that the bullet penetrated Logan's skull, I recommend rewatching the film itself, because there are additional shots of him with a second hole in his skull from the other bullet. You'll also see the scene where Stryker comments on the bullets going "through" Logan's skull.

Answer (score 1):

I believe he used the sword because he didn't want to damage his claws. going by real world logic a material can cut things with the same hardness, and since adamantium is just as hard as adamantium it should be able to cut adamantium.

Comment: Cutting through an extremely-hard material with a blade of the same material is pretty difficult. You need the blade to be very sharp, and apply a lot of force. There is no evidence in the movies that Wolverine has enough strength to cut through an adamantium armour using his adamantium claws.